# iFrame not displaying in Safari

Tags: html, iframe, safari

One of the sites I'm responsible for has a very odd issue and I feel like I'm up against a wall with it.

When loading

https://www.legacytitle-llc.com/resources/sellers-net-sheet/

in safari, the iframe (Net Sheet) doesn't load.  If I open another browser tab and open the iFrame only, it loads, and if I then refresh the original page, it shows up.

How can I get the iFrame to load with the page when a user first hits it?

Comment: fix all of your code errors https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.legacytitle-llc.com%2Fresources%2Fsellers-net-sheet%2F